# jQuery on submit only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form that is loaded dynamically, with a textarea that I must check for spam before submitting. So I wrote something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').live('submit',function(){
        if ( $('form textarea').val().match(/https?:\/\/|www\.|\.com/) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
});
```

And it works fine, the first time. However, if I click on the submit button again, the form is submitted without going through the validation. There are some related questions in SO already, but I've tried their answers and can't seem to make it work. I tried for example attaching the listener to the document rather than the form, and using the `on` method rather than `live`, but with no luck yet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's a simple check for URLs. Didn't think it was important, but I've added it to the code.

Answer (score 3):

The `form` in `$('form textarea')` may not be the same form that triggered the submit event, to use the form that triggered the event use `this`

```
$('form').live('submit',function(){
    if ( $('textarea', this).val().match(/https?:\/\/|www\.|\.com/) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
})
```

Comment: +1!
And just to make the code more readable, you could just return the if block instead :)

Comment: Unfortunately this was not it.